# How to hide/remove the sub-grid filter in MS Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: filter, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm searching for a way to remove/hide this filters:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQBFW.png]

There is already a filter for the records list from *Customize the System -> Entities -> Opportunity -> Views* options. So I don't need this sub-grid filters, but I can't find a way to delete/hide them or remove their filtering ability. I am open to suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove that filters.

Please consider that the second dropdown (`Include`) is a special one.